# Internal and two external monitors go suddenly black when playing game and then trying to start a show on Netflix

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, streaming, gaming

I'm playing City of Heroes on two accounts. It's an old enough game that it doesn't stress the computer much especially since non-focused windows operate at 10FPS max by game settings. I have been playing on two accounts forever. One is full screen (regular window, not even borderless) on monitor one. Monitor two is split between the second game and Netflix in an Edge window (have to use Edge... Chrome is evil and Brave doesn't run streaming well)

Every now and then, with no regularity, I'm doing something on the computer - maybe checking an email or checking my character builds in another tool when I click back into the game windows and try to unpause Netflix. When I do, both screens go black.

I can hear the video playing on Netflix, but nothing on the two external screens or the regular laptop. If I unplug all the external monitors, still nothing. Tried Win+P. Nothing. The only thing that seems to work is pressing the power button to hibernate the laptop then bringing it back. Then everything works fine for a long time (though it's only a matter of time...)

The only consistency is that it only happens when touching online streaming. Netflix... sometimes Crunchyroll.